# Getting error while connecting sybase laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sybase

Below error I'm getting while connecting sybase with laravel.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql'
> (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql
> (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so
> (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol:
> mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
> Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried:
> /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_oci (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_oci: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory),
> /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_oci.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_oci.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown
> on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried:
> /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_oci (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_oci: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory),
> /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_oci.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_oci.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown
> on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'pdo_odbc' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_odbc
> (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_odbc: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_odbc.so
> (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_odbc.so: undefined symbol:
> pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_odbc'
> (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_odbc
> (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_odbc: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_odbc.so
> (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_odbc.so: undefined symbol:
> pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0

I edited php.ini file.

using below dependency in composer.json

```
 "abram/laravel-odbc": "dev-master",
 "agomez/laravel-odbc-driver": "^1.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says it is because of pdo_mysql.
I solved the problem this way:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove php-common

sudo apt-get install php-common php-mysql php-cli
```

Now there is no error and php -m shows it has everything
If still issue is not being solve then find the php.ini file and remove ; from line `extension=pdo_mysql`.